# CKeditor removes ul list

Tags: html, replace, html-lists, ckeditor, config

I am copying html code which has "ul","li" tags, clicking "Source" and pasting it to CKEditor. However, when i go to design, it replaces those tags with "

". Is this a bug or did i configure something wrong? Below is the config.js file content.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
// Define changes to default configuration here.
// For the complete reference:
// http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

// The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker'] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools'] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'] },
    { name: 'paragraph' },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];


// Remove some buttons, provided by the standard plugins, which we don't
// need to have in the Standard(s) toolbar.

config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/Admin/BrowseImage';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/Admin/UploadImage';
```

Comment: This is not ckeditor problem .. check your server side scripting language configuration. how it is handling the tag... i hope you will get the solution....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using latest CKEditor (4.1) which comes with [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter). It means that lists will be cleared out of your content unless you have either `list` plugin loaded with all the features (buttons and commands) or explicitly defined `config.allowedContent` to accept lists.

It also means that if you remove list buttons, editor assumes that you don't want list in your content and they're simply gone. Your `config.toolbarGroups` has no `list` entry and this the root of your problem. You can check whether tag is allowed by typing this in your console:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorInstance.filter.check( 'li' );
>> false
```

When you add something like this to your `config`, lists will be back in the editor with UI:

`{ name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list' ] }`

If you really want to preserve your toolbar but allow lists, you can specify:

[`config.extraAllowedContent = 'ul ol li'`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent).

Also read more about [allowedContent rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) to know more and use things intentionally.